# Groovy/Java regex looping through matches on pattern

Tags: java, regex, groovy

I have a string that holds some bytes represented in hex that I want to extract. For example:

```
String str = "051CF900: 00 D3 0B 60 01 A7 16 C1  09 9C"
```

I want to extract the values and concatenate them together in a string so that it looks like:

```
00D30B6001A716C1099C
```

My attempt:

```
String stream = "";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b[A-F0-9]{2}\\b");
matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
matcher.find{ newByte ->
  println(newByte);
  stream += newByte;
};
println(stream);
```

When I try to add each byte to the `stream` it seems to stop looping. If I remove that line each byte is printed out successfully. Why would the loop break when I add `newByte` to `stream`?

Comment: Why are you using regex? You can achieve this with String Opearation only.

Comment: The real string is a little more complex like `051CF900: 2D 36 00 2B 2D 36 00 2B  00 B6 0B 60 01 6C 16 C1  -6.+-6.+ ...\`.l..   ` and I have no guarantee what the remaining characters will be, I was trying to simplify for posting. It's the principle that I am trying to learn.

Comment: 10 questions @Reimeus? I have only asked 4 questions and I have accepted an answer on every single one. I value all the answers to my questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As this is Groovy, you can change all of your code to:

```
String stream = str.findAll( /\b[A-F0-9]{2}\b/ ).join()
```

Answer (score 3):

For Groovy, you will need to *find all* matches from your `String`. Replace:

```
matcher.find { newByte ->
```

with

```
matcher.findAll { newByte ->
```